# How to get date for each post?

Tags: date, date-time

I'm using the following to get the date of each post:

```
while (have_posts()) : the_post();
//some html
<li class="icon-date"><?php the_date('Y-m-d');?></li>
<li class="icon-time"><?php the_date('H:i:s');?></li>
```

However, I am only getting the date for first post why is that?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

I ran into the same problem several times, following changes worked for me in the past:

```
while (have_posts()) : the_post();
//some html
<li class="icon-date"><?php echo get_the_date( 'Y-m-d' ); ?></li>
<li class="icon-time"><?php the_time( 'H:i:s' ); ?></li>
```

Instead of `the_date()`, use `get_the_date()`.
The only thing to be aware of, is that values returned by `get_the_date()` have to be echoed.

Looking at [the Codex page](http://codex.wordpress.org/the_date) there is a **special note** about `the_date()`.

> When there are multiple posts on a page published under the SAME DAY, the_date() only displays the date for the first post (that is, the first instance of the_date()). To repeat the date for posts published under the same day, you should use the Template Tag the_time() or get_the_date() (since 3.0) with a date-specific format string.

Also, If you want to control the format in wich `get_the_date()` is returned in Admin, you can use `get_option('date_format')`. This way if you change the date format in the Admin, these changes will me made in your code too.

```
while (have_posts()) : the_post();
//some html
<li class="icon-date"><?php echo get_the_date( get_option('date_format') ); ?></li>
<li class="icon-time"><?php the_time( 'H:i:s' ); ?></li>
```

Answer (score 0):

When there are multiple posts on a page published **under the SAME DAY, the_date() only displays the date for the first post (that is, the first instance of the_date())**. To repeat the date for posts published under the same day, you should use the Template Tag [the_time()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/the_time) or [get_the_date()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/get_the_date) (since 3.0) with a [date-specific format string](http://codex.wordpress.org/Formatting_Date_and_Time).
Use  to add the date set in the admin interface.

For more information visit [this page](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_date).

So according to the wordpress codex reference the correct code will be as following :

```
while (have_posts()) : the_post();
//some html
<li class="icon-date"><?php echo get_the_date('Y-m-d');?></li>
<li class="icon-time"><?php the_time('H:i:s');?></li>
```