# Using system date format

Tags: posts, functions, date

I have WordPress theme and I use get_the_date function to display post data :

```
<?php echo get_the_date( 'M-d-y' ); ?>
```

But it seems it will be better to use get_option( 'date_format' ).

How can I display post data using get_option function?

Comment: What have you tried? This question may help https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/90321/how-to-get-date-for-each-post

Comment: have a look at the core code https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_date/ - it seems to indicate that leaving the date format empty calls in the option...

Answer (score 1):

Calling `get_the_date( get_option('date_format') );` will return the exact same value as `get_the_date();` this is because by default if a date format is not specified when the function is called it will use `get_option('date_format');` as can be seen from the following snippet taken from the `get_the_date()` function itself:

```
if ( '' == $d ) {
    $the_date = mysql2date( get_option( 'date_format' ), $post->post_date );
} else {
    $the_date = mysql2date( $d, $post->post_date );
}
```